# How to block NetworkManager from changing a line from dhclient.conf when merging?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, dhclient

In dhclient.conf I have a line

send host-name = gethostname();

which I do not want to be changed by NM to

send host-name = '<current short host name>'

when generating the file in /var/lib/NetworkManager.

Any idea how to do that in Ubuntu 20.04?

gethostname() returns the fqdn of the host, which is mandatory when you have multiple domains on network. Default behavior of NM is wrong for my case. It might help for roaming cases and WiFi connections, but not in case of fixed net connections.

Answer (score 0):

I did find a workaround (not solution) for that: do not use the internal dhcp client

For this fix create the file /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf with the content:

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```